# How do I get a clear idea of total reads in firebase / flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am currently developing an app where you can send post and join certain groups, but whenever i post something in the  group, the reads in firebase get around 800-900 every minute (According to the Usage graph) is there a way to know exactly where they are coming from?

I am using Riverpod, providers in my project to avoid constant reading/writing in the firebase.

I have looked for solutions online, I have used snapshots to ensure I don't constantly check in the database. (I am currently have too many files to share but I can provide you with any code snippet.).

I am not very experienced with flutter/riverpod.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    ),
    title: const Text('Post'),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: sharePost,
        child: const Text('Share'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Inside the sharepost function:

```
ref.read(postControllerProvider.notifier).shareTextPost(
        context: context,
        title: titleController.text.trim(),
        selectedCommunity: selectedCommunity ?? communities[0],
        description: descriptionController.text.trim(),
      );
```

ShareTextPost():

```
void shareTextPost({
required BuildContext context,
required String title,
required Community selectedCommunity,
required String description,
}) async {
state = true;
String postId = const Uuid().v1();
final user = _ref.read(userProvider)!;

final Post post = Post(
  id: postId,
  title: title,
  communityName: selectedCommunity.name,
  communityProfilePic: selectedCommunity.avatar,
  upvotes: [],
  imageLink: [],
  videoLink: [],
  downvotes: [],
  commentCount: 0,
  username: user.name,
  uid: user.uid,
  type: 'text',
  createdAt: DateTime.now(),
  awards: [],
  description: description,
);

final res = await _postRepository.addPost(post);
_ref
    .read(userProfileControllerProvider.notifier)
    .updateUserKarma(UserKarma.textPost);
state = false;
res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
  showSnackBar(context, 'Posted successfully!');
  Routemaster.of(context).pop();
});
}
```

AddPost function:

```
FutureVoid addPost(Post post) async {
try {
  return right(_posts.doc(post.id).set(post.toMap()));
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  throw e.message!;
} catch (e) {
  return left(Failure(e.toString()));
}
}
```

Comment: You at least need to provide the code that posts to the group. No one can help you based on the content of the question so far.

Comment: @GrahamD i have added the code which are run by whenever i add a post

Comment: Done, sorry i am not familiar with answering/asking on stackoverflow but thanks for letting me know

Comment: I havent really figured the error, it was gone temporarily but it is back idk how